# How to remove a style attribute from a span element using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website inside an Iframe and I am highlighting search terms within that page. The problem is that when I highlight new search terms, the old search terms remain highlighted.
What I want to do is replace this:

```
<span style='background-color:yellow;color:black;'>job</span>
```

with this:

```
<span>job</span>
```

, or else just remove the style attribute from the span tag.

This is my Javascript function:

```
function getIframeContent(e) {
  var searchTerm = e.data.textValue
  var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + searchTerm + "\\b)", "gim");
  var span = "<span style='background-color:yellow;color:black;'>$1</span>"
  var findText = e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML;
  var enew = findText.replace( /<span style='background-color:yellow;color:black;'>./igm,'<span>');

  e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML = enew;
  var newe = enew.replace(query, span);
  e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML = newe;            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a class instead of using inline styles you can use querySelector and avoid all this headache

```js
function getIframeContent(e) {
  var searchTerm = e.data.textValue
  var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + searchTerm + "\\b)", "gim");
  var span = "<span class='foo'>$1</span>"
  var findText = e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML;
  //        var enew = findText.replace( /<span style='background color:yellow;color:black;'>./igm,'<span>'); // you can search by class instead
  var enew = document.querySelector(".foo");
  enew.classList.remove('foo');
  // so much easier!

  e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML = enew;
  var newe = enew.replace(query, span);
  e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML = newe;
}
```

Comment: but i need to add the class in this js file only so tried adding the  didnt worked how to add class css here only        
        var link = e.srcElement.$html.context.createElement('link');  
  
        // set the attributes for link element 
           link.rel = 'stylesheet';  
      
        link.type = 'text/scss'; 
      
        link.href = 'styles.scss';  
  
        // Get HTML head element to append  
        // link element to it  
        head.append(link);
        e.srcElement.$html.context.getElementsByClassName('spanStylingTarget')[5]; didnt worked out

Answer (score 0):

You could - instead of changing the highlighted text back to what it was - also save the original content of the frame *before* editing it and using the saved original content to find your terms.

```
var findText = null; //for saving the original content
function getIframeContent(e){
    var searchTerm = e.data.textValue
    var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + searchTerm + "\\b)", "gim");
    var span = "<span style='background-color:yellow;color:black;'>$1</span>"
    if(findText === null) {
        findText = e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML;
    }
    e.srcElement.$html.context.body.innerHTML = findText.replace(query, span);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's not enough just to remove the `style` attributes, you need to remove the whole `span` elements, otherwise the DOM will get filled up with these new extraneous elements. A very simple solution is to store the pristine untouched HTML of the IFrame on the first search and then just reset the contents of the IFrame with this before every subsequent search.

In this example, I have just created a 'pretend' Iframe using a div, but the principle should be the same.

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = searchInput.value;
   
  updateIframeContent(searchTerm);
});

let untouchedText = '';

function updateIframeContent(searchTerm) {

  if(!untouchedText) {
    untouchedText = iframe.innerHTML;
  }
  
  var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + searchTerm + "\\b)", "gim");
  var span = "<span style='background-color:yellow;color:black;'>$1</span>"

  var newe = untouchedText.replace(query, span);
  iframe.innerHTML = newe;            
}
```

```css
.pretend-iframe {
  border: solid 2px dimgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>Search:<input name="search-input" id="searchInput"/></label>
  <button id="search-button">search</button>
 </form>
<div class="pretend-iframe" id="iframe">
  <p>
    Vanilla is a spice derived from orchids of the genus Vanilla, primarily obtained from pods of the Mexican species, flat-leaved vanilla (V. planifolia). The word vanilla, derived from vainilla, the diminutive of the Spanish word vaina (vaina itself meaning
    a sheath or a pod), is translated simply as "little pod". Pre-Columbian Mesoamerican people cultivated the vine of the vanilla orchid, called tlīlxochitl by the Aztecs.
  </p>
  <p>
    Pollination is required to make the plants produce the fruit from which the vanilla spice is obtained. In 1837, Belgian botanist Charles François Antoine Morren discovered this fact and pioneered a method of artificially pollinating the plant. The method
    proved financially unworkable and was not deployed commercially. In 1841, Edmond Albius, a slave who lived on the French island of Réunion in the Indian Ocean, discovered at the age of 12 that the plant could be hand-pollinated. Hand-pollination allowed
    global cultivation of the plant.
  </p>
  <p>
    Three major species of vanilla currently are grown globally, all of which derive from a species originally found in Mesoamerica, including parts of modern-day Mexico. They are V. planifolia (syn. V. fragrans), grown on Madagascar, Réunion, and other tropical
    areas along the Indian Ocean; V. tahitensis, grown in the South Pacific; and V. pompona, found in the West Indies, Central America, and South America. The majority of the world's vanilla is the V. planifolia species, more commonly known as Bourbon
    vanilla (after the former name of Réunion, Île Bourbon) or Madagascar vanilla, which is produced in Madagascar and neighboring islands in the southwestern Indian Ocean, and in Indonesia. Madagascar’s and Indonesia’s cultivations produce two-thirds
    of the world's supply of vanilla.
  </p>
  <p>
    Vanilla is the second-most expensive spice after saffron because growing the vanilla seed pods is labor-intensive. Nevertheless, vanilla is widely used in both commercial and domestic baking, perfume manufacture, and aromatherapy.
  </p>
</div>
```